# Referencing data from a cell that is not explicitly defined

Tags: vba, excel

I realize the wording is probably a bit strange with this question, but I'm relatively new to coding so I wasn't entirely sure how to put my problem into words. I want to iterate through a column of data on one sheet, and use each cell in that column as my search term for searching in a given row of a different sheet.

```
Sub Test1()
n = 0
' n is the counter for the number of times that the search term will appear

Dim sn As String
For Each a In Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A5:A34").Value
f = a.Cells
sn = range(a).Value
' each sn is equal to the contents of the cell "a", which will be the serial number of the tooling


For Each c In Worksheets("RunsheetTest").range("A3:R3")
' Defines c as a range with cells A3 to R3?


If InStr(c.Cells, sn) > 0 Then
n = n + 1
Else
n = n
End If
' If the serial number is found in one of the cells, add 1 to n and move on to the next.

Next c

MsgBox "Searching for " & sn
range(a).Value = n
Next a
' I'm also getting an error here, saying "for loop not initialized", however I thought I initialized it above.

End Sub
```

My biggest question is whether I'm using the right syntax for "f = a.Cells" at the top, since I want to reference the cell that the loop is currently on instead of a specific cell and why the compiler is giving me an error with my loop. Can I not run nested loops in VBA? Also, if any of my comments aren't entirely accurate to what is actually happening, please feel free t let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is "f".  It's hard to understand what you are trying to do with your variable names

Comment: I recommend researching how to properly reference ranges in VBA, as well as how a For Each loop works.  Your general structure is sound (like how you set up the code) but your syntax/method is all off

Comment: I'm in agreement with @RGA. `a`, `c`, and `f` are not very descriptive names for variables and you WILL end up confused eventually. :) I personally start each variable with a 3 letter abbreviation for it data type. Eg, `strSN` for the serial number variable since it is a string or `rngSearchTerm` instead of `a` since it is a range and it contains the value we want to find.

Comment: Whoops! Realized that f was from an older version of the code that I forgot to delete. The problem now is that I want 'sn' to be set equal to the string inside of whatever cell the loop is on in that iteration. For example, in the first loop, 'sn' would equal whatever value is in cell A5, then the second loop would change 'sn' to whatever value is in cell A6, and so on.

Comment: Also, recommend you use `Option Explicit` and fully define ALL variables before you use them.  This will save a lot of type mismatch headache

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim a As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim sn As String

    n = 0
    ' n is the counter for the number of times that the search term will appear

    For Each a In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:A34")
        'f = a.Cells
        sn = a.Value
        ' each sn is equal to the contents of the cell "a", which will be the serial number of the tooling

        For Each c In Worksheets("RunsheetTest").Range("A3:R3")
            ' Defines c as a range with cells A3 to R3?
            If InStr(1, c.Value, sn, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                n = n + 1
            Else
                n = n
            End If
            ' If the serial number is found in one of the cells, add 1 to n and move on to the next.
        Next

        MsgBox "Searching for " & sn
        a.Value = n
    Next
    ' I'm also getting an error here, saying "for loop not initialized", however I thought I initialized it above.

End Sub
```

`a` and `c` are ranges, so you don't reference them by `range(a)` or `range(c)`. Also, just use `Next`, not `Next a`.

Comment: will that first for each work?  You say "a" is a range but you're looping through the values?

Comment: @RGA Good catch! I didn't actually test the code, just corrected the mistakes in OP's code. I'll edit that.

Comment: @Tim - I wanted to make a note for OP that the `else` part of `if` is redundant. Once he understands how the code was changed, it can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Another take on your question -- VBA does support nested loops, but you are better off using built-in Range.Find() method. See example and my comments below:

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim n As Long
    n = 0 ' n is the counter for the number of times that the search term will appear

    Dim sn As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim a As Range

    '' removing ".Value" at the end -- you need to loop through a range
    For Each a In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:A34")
        '' here "a" is already a range object that contains one cell so all you need is:
        n = 0 '' reset the counter for new serial number
        sn = a

        '' to search for a value it is better to use special .Find function on a range, not a loop
        With Worksheets("RunsheetTest").Range("A3:R3")

            Set c = .Find(sn, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                '' you get here only if something is found, otherwise counter will be 0 -- i.e. nothing found
                firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    n = n + 1
                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
            End If

        End With

        MsgBox "Searching for " & sn & " and found it " & n & " times."

    Next a

End Sub
```